# How can I change the URL in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

I have a blog list. When I click on a blog I want to make the URL as the blog name like : `www.domain.com/blog/my-blog-name`.

In my blog list I have the link as blog/blogid(2/3/4) **ex : www.domain.com/blog/1**

When someone visit `www.domain.com/blog/1` then the URL should be `www.domain.com/blog/my-blog-name` **{ the blog name will change as per the blog Id }**

I did so many research on this but no luck. It would be great if anyone help me to get out of this.

I am using laravel 5.4. I am new to laravel also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `slug` field in your database and you will `find` a post using `slug` instead of `id`

Define route:

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PostsControler@findBySlug');
```

Example `http://example.com/post/my-awesome-blog-post`

and in your controller

```php
//PostsController.php

public function findBySlug($slug)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    // return view
}
```

I suggest you use [Eloquent-Sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) to auto create `slug` value from your `title` field

```php
$post = new Post([
    'title' => 'My Awesome Blog Post',
]);
$post->save();
// $post->slug is "my-awesome-blog-post"
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a unique slug or name for your blog , but since names can be duplicate and for the user it is difficult to manually create a unique slug, then I would advise you to do so

```
Route::get('/blog/{id}/{name}',  'BlogController@show');
```

this it will look nice in url, as here for example in stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

You can just override the function getRouteKeyName

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following one!

In your `routes` file:

```
Route::get('blog/{slug}', 'BlogController@show'); // make sure not conflict with resource routes define
```

And then your `BlogController`:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $id = explode($slug, '-')[0]; //get id of post

    // your logic
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Is slug here only id or id with the blog name?

Comment: Hi, slug with id with the blog name! For example: `www.domain.com/blog/1-my-first-blog`

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to show the id in my URL, I want to show only the Blog name, Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, then you need to remove value before fist `-` Just try this first, then try to remove `id`!

Comment: Ok. Thank you I will try it

Answer (score 0):

you can simply take your title from database and use it as a slug like below :

```
$slug = str_replace(' ','-',$yourtitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel mutators setSlugAttribute in your model:

```
public function setSlugAttribute($title){
  $this->attributes['slug'] =  str_replace(' ','-',$title);   
}
```

and write this sample code in your web.php :

```
Route::get('/blog/{slug}',  'BlogController@show');
```

You can use slug in your method.

```
public function findBySlug($slug){

$post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();


}
```